# Xcode and html: how to automatically create </> tags?

Tags: html, ios, css, xcode

I'm a new programmer and just got my first Mac. I've used Sublime Text 3, but now I'm trying to use Xcode for simple html and css lessons. Using Sublime Text, whenever I hit the "tab" button, it would automatically close any tag, speeding the job. If I put  and hit "tab", ST would automatically create a  shortcut. How can I use the same shortcut on Xcode, considering my desire to code on html? Is there any shortcut? I've already learned that "cmd + /" automatically creates commentaries.

Comment: Do not use XCode for HTML, it's not the good tool for that?

Comment: Dont use Xcode for anything other than iOS development, in regards to code writing usability and user friendliness it ranks very close to the bottom of any list.

Comment: Thank you, I'll stick to ST then